# Finding subtitute pluggin (After Switching from Notepad++ to Netbeans 6.8)

Tags: php, ide, netbeans, notepad++, netbeans6.8

i would like to ask about some Notepad++ feature that i couldn't find in netbeans. And this feature is somehow really helpful. It's called 'function list' created by Jens Lorenz.

**this feature will list all of declared function in a PHP files.** So, is there any subtitute plugin that i can use to smooth my migration from Notepad++ to Netbeans ?

the main reason i switch is for svn, Phpdoc-support, and easiness maintaining medium-size web project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of Netbeans are you using I am currently doing my php development in Netbeans 6.8 and it already has this functionality.

If you are looking for all functions in all files, i'm not sure that netbeans has this.

When I create a php file it displays all of my functions in the class navigator like this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [developer.com](http://www.developer.com/img/2010/04/BrowsePHPClass.png))</sub>

If you do not see the navigator you can display it by pressing Ctrl+7

Answer (score 1):

Netbeans has this by default, it is called the 'Navigator' `CTRL + 7`

You may also want to check out `Alt F7` which is the Find Usages shortcut, it comes it very handy for finding every place a variable is used or when a function is declared/used

Comment: Darn! it's right in front of my eyes. maybe i got jet lag. thank you very much